# Checking in nodeJS Express if IIS Client Cert Authentication went ok

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I have some client machines that connect to my IIS server using client certificate authorization. I have a node.js webapp published on IIS (using iisnode) that receives the requests from the clients.

Is there a way in express to know if the authentication was ok? I know that if the authentication was not ok the http request does not reach to express because it is rejected but I need a field to check if it was ok, because I access the same webapp without ssl and I this particar request only needs to be called if the call was using the client ssl authentication.

I tried with `req.socket.authorized` but it is `undefined` and with `req.socket.getPeerCertificate(true)` I am getting `TypeError: req.socket.getPeerCertificate is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
req.secure
```

> A Boolean property that is true if a TLS connection is
>   established. Equivalent to:
>
> 'https' == req.protocol;

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.secure